# How to get 'Code' for OAuth 2.0 response type?

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm looking to get the raw data from Google Analytics.

For that, I need to use OAuth 2.0 for authentication. But for that I need an Access Token. To get the Token I need to give `response_type='code'`.

But I don't know where to get that value of 'code'. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Side note, you will not get "RAW" data from Google Analytics via the API. The data you get is already processed by the same rules as the data in the GA interface.

Comment: Please read `Oauth 2.0` documentation first. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: Thanks a lot..Eike and dikesh